# How to count vertical and horizontal lines in objects using matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to recognize operators and numbers depending on their features and asking how to classify and count vertical and horizontal lines in objects using matlab, i have images like this [image: img1] and want to know there's one vertical line and one horizontal line for example. I tried `edge(I,'canny')` and got this image [image: img2] anyone can help me more?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: horizontal lines: 1, Vertical lines: 1. @SardarUsama

Comment: Can there be multiple lines on the same height? E.g. `I = [0 0 0 0 0; 1 1 0 1 1;0 0 0 0 0]` would have two horizontal lines.

Comment: Are the lines always horizontal or vertical, or will they sometimes be tilted or even diagonal?

Answer (score 0):

The Hough image transform will give you information on the orientation of the line segments within an image:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/hough.html

Comment: I would try to compute a skeleton of the image (https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11123-better-skeletonization) before applying the hough transform.